# Azure Table TableClient Response - ETag

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, etag

Posted a few variations of a theme on this question but don't seem to have asked the right question and have also dug more into my problem.

So...

I am querying Azure Table Storage using the `Azure.Data.Table TableClient` with the `GetEntityAsync<Type>(partitionKey, rowKey)` method

---

**Update - TableClient Calling Code**

using the following code:

Initialize the tableclient:

```
public AzureTableService(string tableName, string storageUri, string accountName, string storageAccountKey) 
{
         tableClient  = new TableClient(
         new Uri(storageUri),
         tableName,
         new TableSharedKeyCredential(accountName, storageAccountKey));
}
```

Get the TableEntity

```
public async Task<TableEntity> GetEntityAsync(string partitionKey, string rowKey) 
{
        var response = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<TableEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        return response.Value;
}
```

---

in two ways:

1. With TableEntity as the type
2. With User as the type

`TableEntity` is the type `Azure.Data.Table.TableEntity` which itself inherits `Azure.Data.Table.ITableEntity`. `ITableEntity` defines the properties `ETag Etag`, `string PartitionKey`, `string RowKey`, and `DateTimeoOffset? Timestamp`.

`User` is a class which inherits from `ITableEntity` and therefore has those same properties alongside strings for Forename, Surname, Mobile and Address.

---

**Update - User Object Definition**

```
public class User : ITableEntity
{
    public User() { }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

---

As such both are valid to use as the type for the method `GetEntityAsync<type>` as they both implement the same interface.

If I use the `User` type the returned object serialised as Json is:

```
{
    "partitionKey": "partitionKey",
    "rowKey": "rowKey",
    "timestamp": "2023-02-09T22:28:54.0242121+00:00",
    "eTag": {},
    "forename": "forename",
    "surname": "surname",
    "mobile": "mobile",
    "address": "address"
}
```

If I use the `TableEntity` type the returned object serialised as Json is:

```
{
    "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2023-02-09T22%3A28%3A54.0242121Z'\"",
    "PartitionKey": "partitionKey",
    "RowKey": "rowKey",
    "Timestamp": "2023-02-09T22:28:54.0242121+00:00",
    "Address": "address",
    "Forename": "forename",
    "Mobile": "mobile",
    "Surname": "surname"
}
```

Neither is populating the ETag correctly - `User` has a value of `ETag: {}` and `TableEntity` has a valid string value of an ETag `"W/\"datetime'2023-02-09T22%3A28%3A54.0242121Z'\""` **BUT** it is is a `string` with a property name of `odata.etag` **NOT** an object of type `ETag` named ETag as per the `ITableEntity` implementation.

Further to this...

when I do a delete operation and require the ETag ifMatch for validation the validation works using the `odata.etag` property value and seemingly not using the ETag property as implemented with ITableEntity.

---

**Update - Delete Method**

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteItemAsync(TableEntity item, bool forceDelete)
{
        var response = await tableClient.DeleteEntityAsync(item.PartitionKey, item.RowKey, forceDelete? ETag.All : item.ETag);
        if (response.Status == 200 || response.Status == 201 || response.Status == 204) { return true; }
        else { throw new Exception($"The response was {response.Status} - {response.ReasonPhrase}"); }
}
```

---

So in effect - the ITableEntity implements a property ETag that is not being set and does not support the ETag property for validation.

I am SO confused - what do I need to do to get the ITableEntity ETag property assigned using the `Azure.Data.Table.GetEntityAsync<TableEntity>(PK, RK)` method and used in the `Azure.Data.Table.DeleteEntityAsync(PK, RK, ETag)` validation?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete code please? Also include the code for your `User` type.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [ETag Properties and OData MetaData](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/16315/files/556f93f1ee937f6a1b15d42ffbbbd4a7b5234e26#diff-c2caa7732ea13a7c296b8f174116972557b410bebb80989646add2ddf81de72b)

Comment: @GauravMantri - Question updated with the code for setting the tableClient, getting the entity, the User object class and the delete method.

Comment: I did just look at the link you provided @RajeshM and can see the extension method ToOdataAnnotatedDictionary strips the ETag property from teh TableClient Dictionary - but don't see why it would be doing this when that extension is not being called. ETag should be available?

Comment: ToOdataAnnotatedDictionary is not a built-in method in the .NET Framework or from any standard libraries.  And it is likely a custom extension method defined by a particular application or library. And it is used to convert an IDictionary<string, object> object representing a table entity's properties to a dictionary with OData annotations.

Comment: @haPartnerships Is this issue resolved? if so post it here as an answer to help community members with the same type of issue.